# paypal payments advanced missing token error

Tags: iframe, paypal

I've been trying to get a transaction through on a PayPal payments advanced account for a few days now with no luck. I've done some searches for an answer, but none seem to fit. Here is what I am doing: I get a secure token with something like this:

```
USER=myuser&VENDOR=myvendor&PARTNER=PayPal&PWD=mypassword&TRXTYPE=S&AMT=750&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=1394403275938
```

This is sent to https://payflowpro.paypal.com and gets the token fine:

```
RESULT=0&SECURETOKEN=XgOx4ldQQgE2z7UeTalxMAgdu&SECURETOKENID=1394403275938 &RESPMSG=Approved
```

I have my hosted page configured for layout C, and after getting the token I try to open an iframe with something like:

```
<iframe src="https://payflowlink.paypal.com?MODE=LIVE&SECURETOKENID=1394403275938&SECURETOKEN=XgOx4ldQQgE2z7UeTalxMAgdu" name="test_iframe" width="570px" height="540px"></iframe>
```

This always ends up with the iframe filled with some error html, indicating:

> Some required information is missing or incorrect. Please correct the
>   fields below and try again.
>
> Error: Token is missing. Please return to the website from where you
>   started your purchase and try again.

What am I doing wrong? I have verified in manager.paypal.com that the account is set to live mode, and I've tried getting the token with both the default manager account and a new user I created, but both end up with the same error page.

Thanks!

Kent

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I had the same issue but it turns out the account was set to test mode in manager.paypal.com.  I was under the impression that the distinction between using test/live mode was all based upon which server you send requests to, but nope.

Answer (score 0):

Spotted the error and fixed it - if you look at the request I send to PayPal to get the token, I'm sending an id like: "1394403275938"

If you look at PayPal's response, they are sending "1394403275938 " with a space on the end. I put it some code to update the id that I'm tracking with whatever PayPal sends back, and then use that in the link to payflow, and now it all works. Why in the world is PayPal modifying the id that I send in? That seems completely wrong.

Kent

Answer (score 0):

A final note - after correcting the above, I was getting errors on the subsequent transactions about the security token not found. I figured this was likely due to the space that PayPal was appending to my token id, so I then generated token ids of exactly 36 chars, instead of - as the docs say - 36 chars max. This has corrected my final issues.

Kent